# A question on Characteristic polynomial of complex $n\times n $ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

On one of linear algebra book i found the problem which need to determine the characteristic polynomial of the complex $n\times n$ matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&\cdots &1\\
1&0&1&\cdots &1\\
\vdots&\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots\\
1&\cdots &1&0&1\\
1&\cdots &1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I don't have any concept to find characteristic polynomial of such kind. Would you say something about it? Thank you.

Comment: If you know the definition of characteristic polynomial, and you know about mathematical induction, that should get you started. You could also try doing a few small cases first. Another way to get there: it should be easy to find the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach is the following. Letting $I$ denote the $n \times n$ unit matrix, then
$$
M+I=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&\cdots &1\\
1&1&1&\cdots &1\\
\vdots&\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots\\
1&\cdots &1&1&1\\
1&\cdots &1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly the image of (the linear map associated to) this matrix is one-dimensional, so its kernel has dimension $n-1$, which means $n-1$ eigenvalues $0$. And the (row) vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is an eigenvector with respect to the eigenvalue $n$. So $M+I$ is similar to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n&&&\cdots &\\
&0&&\cdots &\\
\vdots&\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots\\
&\cdots &&0&\\
&\cdots &&&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(off-diagonal zeroes omitted), and $M = (M+I) - I$ is similar to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n-1&&&\cdots &\\
&-1&&\cdots &\\
\vdots&\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots\\
&\cdots &&-1&\\
&\cdots &&&-1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which yields the characteristic polynomial
$$
(x - (n-1)) \cdot (x+1)^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Self-comment: working out the cases $n=1, 2, 3$, as suggested by @GerryMyerson might have helped pointing in this direction.

Comment: Thank you. After all I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of a question that is treated more generally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/18880).

There are not many transformations of a matrix that have easily predicted effects both on  matrix itself and on the characteristic polynomial (the main operation that leaves the characteristic polynomial *invariant* is any change of basis, i.e., conjugation by some invertible matrix, but even in the simplest cases this combines row and column operations so I wouldn't classify this as having an easily predicted effect on the matrix). However there is one such operation: adding a multiple $cI_n$ to the matrix shifts all roots of the characteristic polynomial up by $c$ by the very definition of the characteristic polynomial, in other words it substitutes $X-c$ for $X$. In this case doing this for $c=1$ is a good idea, because it gives the all-one matrix which I shall call $A_n$.

Since all columns of $A_n$ are equal, its rank is $1$, which imples that its kernel, which is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$, has dimension $n-1$. The unique remaining eigenvalue must have as eigenspace the column space of $A_n$, and an immediate computation shown that the associated eigenvalue of $A_n$ is $n$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial of $A_n$ is $X^{n-1}(X-n)$. The charecteristic polynomial of $M$ is obtained from it by substituting $X+1$ for $X$, giving $$(X+1)^{n-1}(X+1-n).$$

Comment: Thank you all. I think now every thing is okay.