# Find the value of the following $n \times n$ determinantes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find the value of the following $n \times n$ determinantes

1. $$\begin{vmatrix}
   a_1+x & x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
   x & a_2+x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
   x & x & a_3+x & \ldots & x \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
   x & x & x & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
   \end{vmatrix}$$
2. $$\begin{vmatrix}
   a_1+x & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n \\ 
   a_1 & a_2+x & a_3 & \ldots & a_n \\ 
   a_1 & a_2 & a_3+x & \ldots & a_n \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
   a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
   \end{vmatrix}$$

Both seem to be equally complicated to solve, I reckon that it's needed to subtract the $x$ from the diagonal in each term. I tried by subtracting the $(k-1)$-th row from the $k$-th row, however that doesn't really lead me to anything more comfortable whatsoever. So help is greatly appreciated, also perhaps a link to some methods on solving these kind of problems, would also be helpful.

Comment: The second case falls immediately under the category [characteristic polynomial of a rank 1 matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/18880), which would make it a duplicate question. The first one is somewhat different though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 2)** Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & .. &a_n \\
a_1 & a_2 & .. &a_n \\
a_1 & a_2 & .. &a_n \\
...&...&...&...\\
a_1 & a_2 & .. &a_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A$ has rank $1$ and hence $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $n-1$, and hence has algebraic multiplicity at least $n-1$.

As the trace is the sum of eigenvalues, the last eigenvalue is $a_1+a_2+..+a_n$.

Thus
$$
\det(\lambda I-A) =\lambda^n -(a_1+...+a_n) \lambda^{n-1}
$$

Now replace $\lambda$ by $-x$.

**For 1)** Subtract the last row from each of the previous $n-1$. You get
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
x & a_2+x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
x & x & a_3+x & \ldots & x \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
x & x & x & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
0 & a_2 & 0 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
0 & 0 & a_3 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
x & x & x & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

This determinant is a linear function in $x$. Therefore
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
x & a_2+x & x & \ldots & x \\ 
x & x & a_3+x & \ldots & x \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
x & x & x & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=ax+b$$

Now when $x=0$ we get
$$b=a_1 ... a_n$$

All you have to do next is do row expansion by the last row in
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
0 & a_2 & 0 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
0 & 0 & a_3 & \ldots & -a_n \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
x & x & x & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$
in order to find the coefficient of $x$.

**For 2), without eigenvalues:** Transpose the matrix, and then add all rows to the first. We get:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n \\ 
a_1 & a_2+x & a_3 & \ldots & a_n \\ 
a_1 & a_2 & a_3+x & \ldots & a_n \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & a_1 & a_1 & \ldots & a_1 \\ 
a_2 & a_2+x & a_2 & \ldots & a_2 \\ 
a_3 & a_3 & a_3+x & \ldots & a_3 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
a_n & a_n & a_n & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x & a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x & a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x & \ldots &a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x\\ 
a_2 & a_2+x & a_2 & \ldots & a_2 \\ 
a_3 & a_3 & a_3+x & \ldots & a_3 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
a_n & a_n & a_n & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=(a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots &1\\ 
a_2 & a_2+x & a_2 & \ldots & a_2 \\ 
a_3 & a_3 & a_3+x & \ldots & a_3 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
a_n & a_n & a_n & \ldots & a_n+x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now if you do each row minus $a_i$ row one you get
$$=(a_1+a_2+..+a_n+x)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots &1\\ 
0 & x & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & x & \ldots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& &\ddots& \vdots\\
0& 0 & 0 & \ldots & x \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: I see, so it can't be solved without eigenvalues? I mean you can't just solve it by "modifying" the values in the grid, since we still haven't learned eigenvalues and matrices ranks :/

Comment: @AleksXPO Yes you can, I added a solution.

Comment: The last part : "Now if you do each row minus $a_i$ row one you get" are you rewriting it as $a_i + 0$?

Comment: @AleksXPO No. I mean Row 2 minus $a_2$ times Row 1 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with induction, but you can try it for both forms you mentioned in your question.

For the first one the determinant is $$D_1=\prod_{j=1}^n a_j + \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_{n-1}\leq n} a_{i_1} a_{i_2}  \cdots a_{i_{n-1}} x$$

For the second one $$ D_2= x^n +\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^{n-1}$$

I get these formulae by trying the dterminants for $n=1,2,3,4$, you can check [this](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#determinant%28%7B%7Ba%2Bx,x,x,x%7D,%7Bx,b%2Bx,x,x%7D,%7Bx,x,c%2Bx,x%7D,%7Bx,x,x,d%2Bx%7D%7D%29) and [this](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#determinant%28%7B%7Ba%2Bx,b,c,d%7D,%7Ba,b%2Bx,c,d%7D,%7Ba,b,c%2Bx,d%7D,%7Ba,b,c,d%2Bx%7D%7D%29) for example, then easily you can extract such equalities for  $D_1$ and $D_2$, then by induction you prove  the result for every $n$. If you got stuck in any step of the induction, just drop a comment.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Let

\begin{align}
T_n &=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & x & x & \cdots & x \\
x & a_2+x & x & \cdots & x \\
x & x & a_3+x & \cdots & x \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x & x & x & \cdots & a_n+x
\end{vmatrix} \\
 &=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1+x & x & x & \cdots & x \\
-a_1 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-a_1 & 0 & a_3 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-a_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}

Expand $T_n$ with the last column, and we can get

$$
T_n = x a_1 a_2 \cdots a_{n-1} + a_n T_{n-1}
$$

It's obvious that

$$
T_1 = a_1 + x
$$

By induction, we can get

$$
T_n = x \sum^n_{j=1} \prod^n_{\scriptstyle i=1 \atop \scriptstyle i\ne j} a_i + \prod^n_{i=1} a_i
$$