# True/false questions about minimal and characteristic polynomials of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> We have the matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &2  &2 \\ 
>  2& 0 &2 \\ 
>  2& 2 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$, then one of the following is true:
>
> 1. $f_A(x)=m_A(x) $
> 2. The matrix $C=A^4-4A^2+5I$ isn't diagnolizable over $\mathbb R$
> 3. For the matrix $B=A^5+6A^3+A^2-I$ we have $f_B(x)\neq m_B(x)$
> 4. For the matrix $B=A^5+6A^3+A^2-I$ we have $f_B(x)$ is a simple polynomial over $\mathbb C$

EDIT: I get that $f_A(x) = x(2+x)(2-x)$ and it looks like I can't zero the matrix with any smaller combination than $f_A$, so it's maybe true.

For 2 I get that eigenvalues of $A$ aren't zeroing $x^4-4x^2=x^2(x^2-4)=-5$, I'm not sure what to make of it though.

For 3, we have $f_B(x) = x^2(x^3+6x+1)-1$ (?) that can't be a minimal polynomial so that's maybe true.

For 4, I don't think it's true for the same reason as 3.

Notes: $f_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of A, a "simple" polynomial: $x(x+1)$, not "simple" poly': $x^2(x+3)$

Comment: $f_A$ is the characteristic polynomial? Then your 1. is wrong, cause the polynomial you give has degree 5, but $A$ is a $3$-matrix

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about $f_A$, now it's fixed. @martini

Comment: Same problem with (3).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I see, what is this polynomial for 3 then? what can we learn from it?

Comment: How did *you* computed $f_B$ in (3)?

Comment: And what is a  "simple polynomial"?

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of $A$ don't zero $B$, I don't know how to compute $f_B$...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla  that's a "simple" polynomial $x(x+3)(x+7)$, this isn't: $x^2(x+5)$, it probably has a term that I don't know.

Comment: If you don't know how to compute $f_B$, what means "For 3, we have $f_B(x) =$..."???

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla it's wrong, let's focus on what is right, what can we learn from $x^2(x^3+6x+1)-1$? and how is it possible to compute $f_B$ from this?

Comment: *Where*  $x^2(x^3+6x+1)-1$ comes from?

Comment: Since it's all we know about $B$, I turned $A^5+6A^3+A^2-I$ to a polynomial and simplified it. @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: Why do you think that such an idea will work? Idea that *will* work: you can ease the computation of $B$ using that $f_A(A) = 0$.

Comment: How can you use this? @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: You did not compute $f_A$ correctly.

Comment: $A^3 -12A - 16I = f_A(A) = 0\implies A^3 = 12A + 16I$.

Comment: So we can plug that into $A^2(A^3+6A+1)-1$ (twice) and get $17A^2 + 216A +15$, is that $f_B$? @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: $17A^2 + 216A +15I = B = \cdots$. Now, you can compute $f_B$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla btw, this has roots that aren't integers,  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=17x%5E2%2B216x%2B287 (it's a little different because I had a small error before) so even if we'll plug $B$ there to check if only one of the roots are enough for the minimal polynomial, it probably won't, so that means that $f_B(x)= m_B(x)$. How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is real and symmetric, so it must be diagonalisable. Therefore the minimal polynomial (supposedly called $m_A$) has simple roots.

The matrix $A+2I$ has rank $1$ and trace $6$, so [its characteristic polynomial is $X^2(X-6)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/904927/18880), and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (supposedly called $f_A$) is obtained from it by substituting $X+2$ for $X$: $f_A=(X+2)^2(X-4)$ (equivalently, you can see directly that $\lambda=-2$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity$~2$, and the remaining eigenvalue must be $4$ to make their sum equal to $0$, the trace of$~A$). Since this has a double root, point 1 must fail. In fact $m_A=(X+2)(X-4)$ is now forced.

Any polynomial of a diagonalisable matrix is diagonalisable (on the same basis of eigenvectors), so point 2 must be false as well.

In fact, there is a eigenspace for $A$ of dimension$~2$ (for eigenvalue $\lambda=-2$ of $A$), and this is contained in the eigenspace of any polynomial $P[A]$ of$~A$ (for the eigenvalue $\lambda=P[-2]$ of $P[A]$), so $f_{P[A]}$ always has a  multiple root, and can never be equal to $m_{P[A]}$ (for the same reason as for $f_A$ and $m_A$ above). So point 3 is true and point 4 is false, independently of the precise polynomial $P=X^5+6X^3+X^2-1$ used there.

Comment: Can we actually find $f_B$ from the given? And if so, how?

Comment: Yes, $P[A]$ acts on the $2$-dimensional eigenspace of$~A$ for $\lambda=-2$ by the scalar $P[-2]=-77$ and on the $1$-dimensional eigenspace of$~A$ for $\lambda=4$ by the scalar $P[4]=1423$, so $f_B=(X+77)^2(X-1423)$.

Comment: What is $P[x]$? Also, by multiple root you mean the $2$ from $f_B=(X+77)^2(X-1423)$? How can you know for sure that $(X+77)(X-1423)$ zero $B$?

Comment: Also, is there another way to find $f_B$ and $m_B$?

Comment: $P[x]$ means the result of substituting $x$ for $X$ into the polynomial $P$. For instance, with $P=X^5+6X^3+X^2-1$ and $x=-2$ one has $(X^5+6X^3+X^2-1)[-2]=(-2)^5+6(-2)^3+(-2)^2-1=-77$, which is the scalar by which $B=P[A]$ acts on eigenvectors for $\lambda=-2$ of $A$. Also "multiple" root is the opposite of "simple" root. I used it at some point instead of "double" because I did not know yet (and did not care) whether it might actually be a triple root (it might happen that $P[-2]=P[4]$ for a certain $P$).

Comment: That $(X+77)(X-1432)$ annihilates $B$ follows from the fact that $(B+77I)(B-1432I)$ acts as $0$ on each of a basis of eigenvectors for$~A$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.