# the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix $A = (\alpha_v^u)$, where $\alpha_v^u = 1- \delta_v^u,$ is equal to $(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

In the [book](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $111$, question $2$,

> Prove that the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix $A = (\alpha_v^u)$, where $$\alpha_v^u = 1- \delta_v^u,$$ is equal to
>   $(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}$.

If we consider $A$ as the matrix of the map $\phi : E \to E, (dim E = n)$, with respect to the basis $e_v$ , we can say that

$$\phi (e_v) = (\sum_u e_u) - e_v$$, so by definition

$$\Delta_\phi(e_1,..., e_n)= \Delta(\phi(e_1), ..., \phi (e_n)) = \Delta (\sum_{u \not = 1} e_u, ..., \sum_{u \not = n} e_u) = det \phi$$, where $\Delta$ is a nonzero determinant function and $\Delta (e_1, ..., e_n) = 1$, and from that the the only contribution will come from the derangement of $e_v$s, but the number of derangements is huge compare to the $(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}$, so how can continue from that ?

I would appreciate help.

**Note:** In [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia), there is a answer to my question, and its link is given, but I would specifically like to learn how to continue from the point that I have arrived because, for example, if I tried to solve this very same question after a month, I will again use a method similar to this one.

**Edit:**

**I'm particularly looking for a proof that continues from where I left.**

**Note 2:**

After 3 months that I have first faced with this question, I have tried to solve it again, and used the same method as the my first attempt above, and stuck in a similar point in the answer given to this question.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem by showing that the number of even derangements minus the number of odd derangements is $\left(n-1\right) \left(-1\right)^{n-1}$ ? I'm not sure whether this is any easier than the original problem. Exercise 9 (c) in [Mark Wildon's *An involutive introduction to symmetric functions*](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/Sym/SymFuncs2017.pdf) does this using symmetric functions theory, but I somehow doubt that you're looking for that proof :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg The continuation might not be easy to understand, but I least I should know that.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I mean I have stuck in the same point in the below answer, so I thought I should try to continue from my starting.

Answer (score 4):

We can use multilinearity: let $v_i:=\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^ne_j   $. We want to compute $\Delta:=\det\left(v_1,\dots,v_n\right)$. Observe that 
$$v_i =\sum_{j=1} ^ne_j-e_i ,$$
hence 
$$\sum_{i=1}^nv_i=n\sum_{j=1} ^ne_j - \sum_{i=1}^ne_i=\left(n-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^ne_i.$$
Consequently replacing the $n$-th element of $\left(v_1,\dots,v_n\right)$ by  $\sum_{i=1}^nv_i$, we get
$$\Delta=\det\left(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},\left(n-1\right)\sum_{i=1}^ne_i \right)=\left(n-1\right)\det\left(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},\sum_{i=1}^ne_i \right).$$
Now,  replace  $v_i$ by $v_i-\sum_{l=1}^ne_l$ to get that 
$$\Delta=\left(n-1\right)\det\left(v_1-\sum_{l=1}^ne_l,\dots,v_{n-1}-\sum_{l=1}^ne_l,\sum_{i=1}^ne_i \right).$$
Since $v_u-\sum_{i=1}^ne_i=-e_u$, we derive that 
$$\Delta=\left(n-1\right)\det\left(-e_1,\dots,-e_{n-1}  ,\sum_{i=1}^ne_i \right),$$
giving the wanted result.

Comment: So, after "Consequently", shouldn't it be like $ v_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} e_i $, so you cannot do that replacement of yours.

Comment: I can, since for any $i\in\left\{1,\dots,n-1\right\}$, the determinant $\det(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_i )$ is zero.

Comment: Ok, what about replacing $v_i$ by $v_i-\sum_{l=1}^ne_l$ ? I mean $\sum_{l=1}^ne_l = v_i + e_i$

Comment: It is just the use of multilinearity of the determinant (when two columns are the same, it is zero).

Comment: Hi again @DavideGiraudo, I revisited your answer, and again stuck at the point "Now, replace $v_i$ by $v_i-\sum_{l=1}^ne_l$", can you edit your answer, so that the answer can become clear for every one.

Comment: Look, last time it took my 16 days to figure out the thing that I was missing, so I think it would be really beneficial if you can explain that point more clearly.