# Spectral decomposition of some special matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A_{n\times n} = aI+bJ$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the matrix of all ones. Is it possible to find the expression of $A^{1/2}$ such that $A^{1/2}A^{1/2} = A$? In particular $A = I_{n\times n} - \frac{(1-\alpha)}{n+\alpha(2-n)}J_{n\times n}$, where $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: There have been a number of previous Questions about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, which is evidently real and symmetric.  Provided $a,b$ are such that $A $ is positive definite, it is possible to take a matrix "square root" but the result is not unique.

Comment: I have given the particular form of $A$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has a real symmetric square root $A^{1/2}$ if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are nonnegative.  The eigenvalues of $J$ have been found in [a number of previous Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia), namely $n$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity one and $0$ as an eigenvalue has multiplicity $n-1$.

Therefore $A = aI+bJ$ has eigenvalues $a+bn$ with multiplicity one and $a$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

So for $A$ to be positive semi-definite (i.e. have nonnegative eigenvalues) it is required that $a \ge 0$ and $a+bn \ge 0$.  This is indeed true for the case "in particular" in the revised Question, where:

$$ a = 1\; , \; b = -\frac{(1-\alpha)}{n+\alpha(2-n)} $$

given that $0\lt \alpha \lt 1$.  When we simplify:

$$ a+bn = \frac{2\alpha}{2\alpha + n(1-\alpha)} $$

Assuming this, we can deduce the existence of positive semi-definite symmetric $A^{1/2}$ and explicitly construct one by taking an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$ to diagonalize it:

$$ D = Q^T A Q $$

where $Q$ has columns that are the orthonormalized eigenvectors and $D = \operatorname{diag}(a+bn,a,\ldots,a)$, so that:

$$ A^{1/2} = Q D^{1/2} Q^T$$

Here we mean to take square roots of the diagonal entries of $D$ to produce $D^{1/2}$, but there are additional matrices $B$ that satisfy the relationship $B^2 = A$.  For example, $B = -A^{1/2}$, but for $n\gt 1$ there are further possible matrix "square roots".

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick and easy way to get a matrix $A^{1/2}$, provided one is willing to limit oneself to solutions of the form

$C = \alpha I + \beta J; \tag 1$

then

$C^2 = \alpha^2 I + 2 \alpha \beta J + \beta^2 J^2 = \alpha^2 I + 2 \alpha \beta J + \beta^2 n J = \alpha^2 I + (2 \alpha \beta + n \beta^2)J, \tag 2$

where we have used the fact that $J^2 = nJ$, which is easily verified; with

$A = a I + bJ \tag 3$

and

$C^2 = A, \tag 4$

since $I$ and $J$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$, we must take

$\alpha^2 = a \tag 5$

and

$2 \alpha \beta + n \beta^2 = b; \tag 6$

then

$\alpha = \pm \sqrt a, \tag 7$

and thus (6) becomes a quadratic equation in $\beta$ whose coefficients are known:

$n\beta^2 + 2 \alpha \beta - b = 0; \tag 8$

enter the quadratic formula:

$\beta = \dfrac{-2\alpha \pm \sqrt{4 \alpha^2 + 4nb}}{2n}; \tag 9$

using (5), we simplify

$\beta = \dfrac{-2\alpha \pm \sqrt{4 a + 4nb}}{2n} = \dfrac{-2\alpha \pm 2\sqrt{a + nb}}{2n} = \dfrac{-\alpha \pm I\sqrt{a + nb}}{n}; \tag{10}$

with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given by (5) and (10) we take

$A^{1/2} = C. \tag{11}$

***Note:*** It is not yet clear to me whether or not all solutions are of this form.  Further investigation required.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: +1 [It is not yet clear to me whether or not all solutions are of this form. ]---> I think not as $A$ itself satisfies a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: $A^2 - 2a A +  a^2 I = (A - aI)^2 =  b^2 J^2 = n b^2 J = nb (bJ) = nb (A - aI) \Longrightarrow A^2 - (2a + nb) A + (a^2 + nab)I = 0$

Comment: Right ! It factors as $(A-(a+nb))(A-a)$ which is not the same thing (neither stronger nor weaker) than saying $sp(A)=[a+nb]+(n-1)[a]$ (spectrum, see other answer).