# Help with this matrix problem about the inverse of a particular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Is the following matrix invertible?

$ \begin{bmatrix} x & a & a & \dots & a \\ a & x & a & \dots & a \\ a & a & x & \dots & a \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a & a & a & \dots & x \end{bmatrix} $

I cannot use "determinants" or other stuff but the rank of the matrix. I really tried hard this problem making a lot of algebra and cases but I didn't find the solution; can someone help me for solving it?

Note: The cases when $x=a$ and $a=0$ 
were covered yet.

Thanks.

Comment: when invertible, the inverse has the same shape, all $y$ on the main diagonal and all else $b.$  Given the dimension $n,$ what are $y$ and $b,$ and when is it impossible to solve for them?

Comment: [This post is relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360), but I don't think that any of the link posts avoid the use of determinants or eigenvalues.  The answer to your question will ultimately be that the matrix is invertible unless we have $x = a$ or $x = -(n-1)a$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix.

Comment: If you’re supposed to use the rank of the matrix, then have you examined when this matrix doesn’t have full rank? Have you tried decomposing it into the sum of a diagonal matrix and one that has all elements equal? That might give you some insights.