# Prove that the following determinant equals $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

We have a $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$. 
 If $i=j$, then $a_{i,j}=1-n$. otherwise, $a_{i,j}=1$. Show that $|A|=0$. 
 I tried using gauss elimination but it just gets too complicated. I also tried to do $R_i \rightarrow R_i-R_1/(1-n)$ for all $i>1$, and then expand over the first column, but it also didn't work for me. Can someone please help?

Comment: The matrix of all ones is often denoted $\mathbf J$.  Your problem concerns $\mathbf J - n\mathbf I$, and it has been discussed in [several previous Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint**:$$
A\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right)=0.
$$