# $B=((b_{ij}))$ where $b_{ij}=1 \, \forall i,j$ and $A=(a-b)i_n+bB$ Prove that $|A|=(a-b)^{n-1}[a+(n-1)b]$

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have the following problem which I do not know how to solve. I found the statement to be a bit confusing. Here's the problem:

If $B=((b_{ij})) \in M_{n\times n}$ where $b_{ij}=1 \, \forall i,j$ and $A=(a-b)i_n+bB$

Prove that $|A|=(a-b)^{n-1}[a+(n-1)b]$

I found the $i_n$ notation to be a bit cofusing, so I do not really understand how matrix A was declared. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Perhaps $i_n$ is meant to denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Did you try looking for definitions of notation from the source?

Comment: If $i_n$ **is** supposed to be an identity matrix, then I'd say that this question is a [duplicate of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360)

Comment: Oh, it could be that. I was a bit confused since it was a lowercase $i$. Maybe it was a typing error. The problem is from a handout that was given in my university. I'll try to solve it assuming that the $i$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I solved it assuming that $i$ was the identity matrix and I was able to get to the answer. So it is a duplicate. What do I have to do? Do I delete the question?

Comment: No, leave it up.  We'll vote to close it, but it is useful to have these duplicate questions around

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for the help!