# Eigenvalues of block Toeplitz matrix with Toeplitz blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, toeplitz-matrices

Consider integers $m,n$ and a $m \times m$-block Toeplitz matrix $A$ consisting of two different types of blocks as follows

\begin{align} 
A_{mn \times mn} 
&= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
B & C & C & \cdots & \cdots & C \\ 
C & B & C & C & \cdots & C \\ 
C & C & B  & C & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots & C \\ 
C & \cdots & \cdots & C & B & C \\ 
C & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & C & B 
\end{bmatrix}
_{mn \times mn} 
,
\end{align}

where $B$'s are diagonal blocks with $B=\frac{1}{m}I_n$ and $C$'s are multiples of the all-ones matrix $J_n$, specifically $C=\frac{1}{mn}J_n$.

I want to compute the eigenvalues of $A$ (I am mainly interested in the value of the 2nd largest eigenvalue since it has a special meaning in graph expansion applications).

Note that in my problem the following conditions also hold for $m,n$:

- $m$ is odd.
- $n$ is prime.
- $m<n$.

I have experimented with such matrices on the computer and I have observed a trend for the spectrum of $A$ which consists of the following eigenvalues:

- $\lambda_1=0$ with algebraic multiplicity $m-1$.
- $\lambda_2=1/m$ with algebraic multiplicity $m(n-1)$.
- $\lambda_3=1$ with algebraic multiplicity $1$.

I do not claim that this is necessarily the answer but at least it was consistent for the pairs of $m,n$ I tried.

Can you suggest how one can go and prove the above claim (if correct) or pinpoint other known results?

**EDIT**

After Omnomnomnom's note that
\begin{equation}
A = \frac 1{mn}\underbrace{\pmatrix{
0&1&\cdots & 1\\
1&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
1&\cdots&1&0}}_{= C_{m \times m}} \otimes J_n + \frac 1m I_{mn}
\end{equation}

I did some computation of the spectrums of the individual matrices. First, the characteristic polynomial of the all-ones $J_n$ is $(\lambda-n)\lambda^{n-1}$ and hence its spectrum (with the multiplicities) is
\begin{equation}
\sigma(J_n)=\{(n,1),(0,n-1)\}.
\end{equation}
For $C$, assume that $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$ are its eigenvalues. By the facts that $\mathrm{det}(C-(-1)I_m)=det(J_m)=0$, $C\mathbf{1}_m=(m-1)\mathbf{1}_m$ and $\mathrm{trace}(C)=\sum_i\lambda_i=0$ it turns out that
\begin{equation}
\sigma(C)=\{(m-1,1),(-1,m-1)\}.
\end{equation}
Suppose that $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ are the eigenvalues of $J_n$ then by the Kronecker product's properties the spectrum of $CJ_n$ consists of the pairwise products $\lambda_i\mu_j, \forall i,j$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are correct and hold for arbitrary $m,n$. It suffices to note that
$$
A = \frac 1{mn}\pmatrix{
0&1&\cdots & 1\\
1&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
1&\cdots&1&0} \otimes J_n + \frac 1m I_{mn}
$$
and use the properties of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

---

In more detail: $C_{m \times m}$ is a [rank 1 update of a scalar matrix,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360) so we find that its eigenvalues are $-1$ with multiplicity $m-1$ and $m-1$ with multiplicity $1$.  On the other hand, $J_n$ has eigenvalues $0$ with multiplicty $n-1$ and $n$ with multiplicity $1$.

It follows that $C \otimes J$ has eigenvalues $0$ with multiplicity $m(n-1)$, $-n$ with multiplicity $m-1$, and $n(m-1)$ with multiplicity $1$.

From there, it suffices to note that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $c \lambda + d$ is an eigenvalue of $c A + dI$.

Comment: I have made some edits based on your response (please see edit). However, the resulting sum of the Kronecker product and the diagonal matrix confuses me. How can I proceed?

Comment: @mgus I'll add in what I had in mind when I have the chance

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now it is clear to me except one thing: if the spectrums of $C$ and $J_n$ are indeed $\sigma(C)=\{(m-1,1),(-1,m-1)\}$ and $\sigma(J_n)=\{(n,1),(0,n-1)\}$, respectively then where is the eigenvalue $-n(m-1)$ of $C \otimes J$ is coming from? I thought it would be $n(m-1)$ with multiplicity $1$. After doing the remaining of the calculations for the eigenvalues of $A$ it seems that this should be true but how? Am I missing some plus or minus somewhere?

Comment: @mgus You're right about $n(m-1)$; I just had an extra minus sign there.

Comment: But if this is the case, then the spectrum of $\frac{1}{mn}C \otimes J$ is $\{(\frac{n(m-1)}{mn}, 1), (-1/m, m-1), (0, (n-1)m)\}$ so adding $1/m$ to this spectrum yields all desired eigenvalues for $A$ except the eigenvalue $1$

Comment: @mgus But we have
$$
\frac{n(m-1)}{mn} + \frac 1m = \frac{mn - n}{mn} + \frac{n}{mn} = \frac{mn}{mn} = 1.
$$

Comment: Ugh, thanks a lot for your help, had some typo in my notes.