# I cannot seem to get the right eigenvalues when using the secular equation (specific case)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix A: \begin{bmatrix}7/3&-2/3&-2/3\\-2/3&7/3&-2/3\\-2/3&-2/3&7/3\end{bmatrix}
which I solve using the characteristic equation like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqFIK.jpg

The problem is, the right eigenvalues are 1 and 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the middle component of the matrix $\color{red}-7/3$?  I don't see the negative sign in that image you linked

Comment: $1$ is not an eigenvalue of the matrix in the question, but if you change the $-7/3$ in the middle to $+7/3$ then $1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$.  The $c\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $cA$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, that is correct, I wrote it in wrong. Fixed it!

Comment: You pulled out the factor of $1/3$ prematurely: you’ve computed $\det(A-\frac13\lambda I)$ so all of your eigenvalues are off by a factor of three.

Comment: @AndreasBlass How would I solve it then? Because when I solve it I get eigenvalues 3 and 9 (with the correct middle 7/3)

Comment: @amd Oh! But I have learned that if all of the elements are divided by three, I can take them out by multiplying the determinant by that fraction for every column/row. Is that wrong?

Comment: Given the corrected version of your question, the quickest way is to use one of the approaches [outlined here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360).

Comment: @Carl see Michael's comment. If you multiply everything by $3$, then the eigenvalues you get are of the form $3\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I know that, however I do not want to calculate the eigenvalue of cA, but A. If you look at my solution via the link I provided, what is it I have done wrong in my calculation (trying to find the eigenvalues for A above)?

Comment: @Carl On the right side of the first $=$, the expression you have is equal to $(1/3)^3\det(3A - \lambda E) = \det(A - \frac 13 \lambda E)$. What you need is $\det(A - \lambda E)$.

Answer (score 3):

You went wrong right off the bat when you expanded $\det(A-\lambda I)$. The main diagonal elements of $A-\lambda I$ are all $\frac73-\lambda$, so when you pulled out a factor of $\frac13$ to simplify your calculations, they should’ve become $7-3\lambda$. What you’ve written down is instead the determinant of $A-\frac\lambda3I$, so all of your eigenvalues are off by a factor of three. To put it a different way, what you’ve done is to compute the eigenvalues of $3A$. It’s OK to scale a matrix in this way to simplify things since if $Av=\lambda v$ then $(cA)v=(c\lambda)v$, but you then have to remember to scale the resulting eigenvalues by $1/c$ to get the eigenvalues of the original matrix.

Note that for this matrix, it’s easy to find eigenvectors and eigenvalues directly, without solving the characteristic equation. It’s of the form $aI+bJ$, where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones and $b\ne0$. $bJ$ is a rank-one matrix with equal row sums, so $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$ and the vector of all $1$s is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $nb$. The eigenvalues of the original matrix are therefore $a$ and $a+nb$, respectively. In this case, $a=3$ and $b=-2/3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

the eigenvalues of the matrix with all elements equal to $1$ (and 3 by 3) are
(0,0,3).

the eigenvalues of the matrix with all elements equal to $-2/3$ (and 3 by 3) are
(0,0,-2).

The eigenvalue of that matrix added to $3I,$ which is your actual matrix, are
(3,3,1).