# Inverting symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Is it possible to find an analytical expression for the innverse of the matrix $A$ defined by :

$$i\neq j \;:\; A_{ij}=x_ix_j$$
$$A_{ii}=\alpha x_i$$

With $\alpha$ a constant and $x$ a vector. If yes, how could I do that please ?

Comment: Why do you think it is invertible?  It looks like an outer product matrix, which typically has rank 1.

Comment: I assume it's invertible since it is a symmetrical matrix

Comment: A matrix of all ones is symmetrical but not invertible.  Positive semi-definite matrices, in general, might not be invertible, since the eigenspace associated with the zero eigenvalue might not have sufficient rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is $D+xx^T$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix such that $d_{ii}=\alpha x_i-x_i^2$. This is a [rank-$1$ update](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926) of $D$. Provided that $D$ is nonsingular, $D+xx^T$ is invertible if and only if $1+x^TD^{-1}x\ne0$. If this is the case, you may apply [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to obtain
$$
A^{-1}=(D+xx^T)^{-1}=D^{-1}-\frac{D^{-1}xx^TD^{-1}}{1+x^TD^{-1}x}.
$$