# How to decompose a matrix whose off-diagonal elements are all the same and non-zero, and all the diagonal elements are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

edited based on Exodd's comments:

For a $m$ by $m$ matrix $A$ whose off diagonal elements are all the same $\rho$, and all the diagnoal elements are the same $\gamma + \rho$ , it can be re-written as

$$A=\gamma I+uu^{T},$$

, u is a vector of length m where each element is $\sqrt{\rho}$

Does above properties make it easier to decompose matrix $A$? e.g. Cholesky/Eigen/LU decomposition.

The only thing I can think of is eigen decomposition:

$$(A-\lambda I)\upsilon=0$$

which becomes

$$(\gamma I+uu^{T}-\lambda I)\upsilon=0$$

this leads to a new eigen problem :
$$(uu^{T}-(\lambda-\gamma) I)\upsilon=0$$

if $\alpha= \upsilon - \gamma$, then
$$(uu^{T}-\alpha I)\upsilon=0$$

how to go further from here ?

Can anyone kindly share some ideas?

Comment: If all diagonal elements of $D$ are equal, then it is easy to obtain the eigencomposition of $A$, since it has the same eigenvectors of $uu^T$

Comment: @Exodd I have updated the question based on your insight. Indeed, this is a new eigen problem and the eigen vectors of $uu^{T}$ is the same as the origina A 's eigenvector

Comment: this exact   formulation has been answered countless times. You can find it and a lot of related question/answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926/determinant-of-a-rank-1-update-of-a-scalar-matrix-or-characteristic-polynomia