# Prove that a positive $n \times n$ matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let constant $0<k<1$. Prove that the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, where its diagonal entries $a_{ii} =1$ and $a_{ij}=k$ for $i \neq j$, is
Positive definite.

By definition, I know that a matrix $A$ is positive definite if $x^T A x>0$ for all vectors $x\neq 0$. And I also know that an $n \times n$ matrix is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive. But I am stuck here.

Any help or hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This seems false. the matrix is the same as $B-(k-1)I$ where $B$ is that rank $1$ matrix consisting of only $k$'s. It follows that $-(k-1)$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$. Of course if you swap the entries $k$ and $1$ and make $k>1$ then it's true.

Comment: No, the matrix with only $1$ as entries (for $k=1)$ is not positive definite for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Generally it is good to try simple examples, in this case a $2 \times 2$ example.

Comment: actually it's never positive definite if the size is at least $2$.

Comment: This statement will only be true if we are also given that $k < 1$.

Comment: @Yorch In the $2 \times 2$ case it is PSD **iff** $|k|<1$.

Comment: The spectrum of the matrix is always $\{ [-(k-1)]^{n-1},[nk-(k-1)]^1\}$

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, I was assuming $k$ was an integer.

Comment: Following the ideas from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360), we can see that the eigenvalues of this matrix will be $1-k$ with multiplicity $1$ and $n-1 + k$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

Comment: I think $1-k$ has multiplicity $n-1$ and the other eigenvalue is $nk+1-k$

Comment: Write $A= (1-k) I + k e e^T$ where $e$ is the vector of ones. Then the eigenvalues are $1-k +nk$ (eigenspace $\operatorname{sp} \{ e \}$) and $1-k$ (eigenspace $\{e\}^\bot$).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful comments and observations. @Yorch, and co. This implies that the question isn't correct right?

Comment: @Pacific That's right

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks again for the observation. I have corrected the question the condition is $0<k<1$. Could you help with the prove. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bit of calculation is needed to prove it for a general $n \times n$ matrix. The fact $\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i{}^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j$  is used.

Let $x=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}$, $x^TAx$ will be of the form
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +  2k \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j.
\end{align}
If  $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j \ge 0$ we're done. So let $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j < 0$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +  2k \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 -2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j +2k \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2+2(1-k) \left(-\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j \right)  \\
&>0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @absolute0 Please why did you use the first equality. I thought the goal was to check if it satisfies $x^T A x >0$

Comment: see the first equality is used in the 3rd  last line to show $x^TAx >0$. that's why it's written.

Comment: oh I see thanks

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $J=\mathbf {11}^T$ be the $n\times n$ ones matrix.  Then

$A= (1-k) I_n + k\cdot J\succeq (1-k) I_n \succ \mathbf 0$
Therefore A is PD.
In words: a PD matrix plus a PSD matrix is PD.

Comment: please why did you use $n \times n$ ones matrix. Since the conditions are $a_{ii} =1$ and $0<a_{ij}<1$.

Comment: Since every off-diagonal entry is the identical, equal to $k$, we can write your matrix as $ D + k \cdot J$ for some diagonal matrix $D$.  Furthermore, since all diagonal entries identically are equal to 1, this implies $D=(1-k)I_n$.