# What are some Hermitian matrices with known formula for determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm wondering if there are some Hermitian matrices with known formula for determinant. For example, according to wiki the determinant of the tri-diagonal matrix

[image]

could be calculated by the recursive formula

$$f_n=a_nf_{n-1}-c_{n-1}b_{n-1}f_{n-2}. $$

What are some other matrices with known formula for calculating the determinant? I'm especially interested in known formula for Hermitian matrices.

Comment: You can research the Vandermonde Determinant, it has a known formula with a very simple derivation.

Comment: The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal entries

Comment: Triangular matrices have an easy formula- they’re also the product of diagonal entries. Look up the block matrix determinant as well

Comment: @FShrike Thanks! I already know the determinant formula for the diagonal/triangular matrices, but rn I'm especially looking for determinant of Hermitian matrices. I'll edit the title to make it clear.

Comment: @duang You might find symmetric and real [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) to be interesting.

Comment: @duang You might also be interested in matrices of the form $\lambda I_n \pm BB^T$, where $B$ is an $n \times k$ matrix with $k$ small (equal to $1,2$ or $3$). The determinant is given by $\lambda^{n-k} \det(\lambda I_k \pm B^TB)$, which is often a much nicer expression. See the [W-A determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity). The case of $k=1$ in particular [has come up on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360) fairly frequently.