# The complement of identity matrix has full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, matrix-rank

I am try to understand why $rank(J_n - I_n) = n$ over any field that does not divide $n-1$ or any infinite field (in particular over $\mathbb{R}$).

$J_n$ is the $n\times n$-Matrix with all ones $J_n[i][j]=1$ for all $i,j\in[n]$.

$I_n$ is the $n\times n$-identity matrix.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Suppose $n-1\ne0$. If $(J-I)x=0$, then $Jx=x$. Since $J^2=nJ$, $nx=nJx=(J^2)x=J(Jx)=Jx=x$. Therefore $(n-1)x=0$. As $n-1\ne0$, we must have $x=0$. Hence $J-I$ is nonsingular and it has full rank. From another perspective, this is all about [rank-one update](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926) of a matrix.

Comment: Alternatively, when $n-1\ne0$, verify that $(J-I)(\frac{1}{n-1}J-I)=I$.

Comment: What deoes title have to do with actual question?? Inverse of the identity matrix is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of $J_n - I_n$ is nonzero in the base field if and only if $J_n - I_n$ is invertible: so let's compute $\operatorname{det}(J_n - I_n)$. Recall that for a diagonalizable matrix its determinant is just the product of its eigenvalues (with multiplicity): we will show that $J_n - I_n$ is diagonalizable and compute these eigenvalues.

First I claim that there are $n - 1$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $J_n - I_n$ all with eigenvalue $-1$ given by (check this):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\0\\1\\0\\\vdots\\0
\end{bmatrix},
\cdots,
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Next I claim that the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\\\vdots\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
of all ones is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n - 1$ (check this too).

This pins down all of the eigenvalues with multiplicity of $J_n - I_n$: we have $\det(J_n - I_n) = -1 \cdot -1 \cdot \cdots \cdot -1 \cdot (n - 1) = (-1)^{n-1}( n - 1)$. In particular $J_n - I_n$ is invertible if and only if $n - 1$ is nonzero in the base field. This is always the case as long as the characteristic of the base field does not divide $n - 1$, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $J_n-I_n$ has the determinant $(-1)^{n-1} \cdot (n-1)$.
Thus if the field has characteristic $0$ or positive characteristic $p$ not dividing $n-1$, then the determinant is nonzero and so the matrix is invertible.