# Finding the inverse of a symmetric $28\times28$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Let $A$ be a $28 \times 28$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $$ a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 28 &\text{if } i = j\\ -1 &\text{if } i \neq j \end{cases} $$ What is the inverse of this matrix?

---

I tried doing it by the adjoint method, but my resolution is wrong. First I tried finding the determinant of $A$, which I believe to be $\det(A) =28^{28}+27-14\cdot28^2-14$. Then, I tried finding the cofactor of $a_{ij}$ where $i=j$, which I believe is $\operatorname{cof}(28) =28^{27}-27-28^3$ and also the cofactor of $a_{ij} $ where $i\neq j$ which I calculated to be $\operatorname{cof}(-1)=28^{26}+27-1+27\cdot28$. Since the matrix is symmetric, I thought that the cofactor matrix is equal to the adjoint matrix, so the elements of the inverse matrix would be:
$$a_{ii}^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{cof}(28)}{\det(A)}$$ and
$$a_{ij}^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{cof}(-1)}{\det(A)}$$
where $i\neq j$. But this doesn't give the correct value. I think it might be a simple mistake, but I really can't find it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in a formula or numerical values? Also, your determinant is incorrect.

Comment: I want values like those that I gave for the determinant and for the cofactors (like $\det(A) =28^{28}+27-14\cdot28^2 - 14$). I put the values like that so it would be clear what products I made. Since you said my determinant is incorrect, I'll explain how I got there. $28^{28}$ is the product of the main diagonal, $27$ is the sum of all the remaining "positive products", $-14\cdot28^2$ is the sum of all "negative products" from odd columns, and $-14$ is the sum of all "negative products" from even columns. I came to this conclusion analysing $2\times2$ and $4\times4$ matrices similar to $A$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $W$   be the 28 by 28  matrix where every entry is $1.$  The simple fact is $$   W^2  = 28 W$$

Your matrix is
$$  A = 29 I - W $$

If there is an inverse matrix $B,$   it i of the same shape, some coefficients  $\beta, \gamma$  with
$$ B = \beta I + \gamma W$$

With these definitions, what values of $\beta, \gamma$   make $AB = I?$

Comment: So I tried multiplying both sides of $B=\beta I+\gamma W$ by $A$ on the left, and ended up with $AB=29\beta I+(29\gamma - \beta) W- \gamma W^2$ but I'm not sure how to make RHS equal $I$. I tried doing $\beta=\frac{1}{29}$ so $29\beta I = I$, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @PrincipeDiSpade  did you use $W^2 = 28 W  \; ? \; \;   $

Comment: Nope. With that I get $\beta =\gamma = \frac{1}{29} $. Is that correct?

Comment: @PrincipeDiSpade  now put your $\beta, \gamma $  into $AB$  and see if it really works

Comment: Yeah, putting it back gives the correct solutions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "it is of the same shape"  This is correct for this quite particular case, but is it obvious?

Comment: @Surb  not obvious.  There are a number of things I   would prefer the OP knew, nothing yet confirms that he knows how to multiply matrices; it would be nice if he found $W^2$  by multiplication, for the 2 by2 and then 3 by3 matrix of all ones

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another way:

Note that $A=29I - e e^T$, where $e$ is a vector of ones. It is straightforward to check that the eigenvalues are $1,29$ hence it is invertible.

To compute $A^{-1}$, solve $Ax=b$.

This is $29x-(e^Tx)e = b$, hence $29 e^T x -(e^Tx)e^T e = e^T b $,
or $e^T x = e^T b$. The first equation can be written as
$29 x = (e^T b)e+b=(I+e e^T)b $, and so $x = {1 \over 29} (I+e e^T)b $, from which we get
$A^{-1} = {1 \over 29} (I+e e^T)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't studied eigenvalues and eigenvectors yet. Will take a look back at this when I have studied those things.

Comment: @PrincipeDiSpade You don't need to know what they are, it was just to demonstrate invertibility. All you need to do is multiply $A$ by the last matrix and check that the answer is $I$.

Comment: I guess you could add  $(ee^T)^2 = e e^T e e^T =  e (e^T e) e^T =  28 e e^T.$  I suspect that remains a sticking point.

Comment: Or just multiply them out $(29I - e e^T) {1 \over 29} (I+e e^T) = I$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, I just saw the word "eigenvalue" and thought I would not understand your answer. It's actually very clear to me otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, let

$$ {\bf A} := (n+1) \, {\bf I}_n - {\bf 1}_n {\bf 1}_n^\top $$

Note that $\bf A$ is a rank-$1$ update of a multiple of the identity matrix.  Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),

$$ {\bf A}^{-1} = \cdots = \frac{1}{n+1} \left( {\bf I}_n + {\bf 1}_n {\bf 1}_n^\top \right) $$