# Find eigenvalues of rank-$1$ update of a multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading online when I came across this problem:

$$ A^2 = J + (k-1) I $$ where $A$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix where $n = k^2 - k + 1$, and $J$ is a matrix with all $1$s and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Is there a quick way from this expression to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the square matrix?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790).

Comment: Eigenvalues of $A$ or of $A^2$?

Comment: Vectors in the null space of $J$ will be degenerate eigenvectors having eigenvalue $(k-1)$