# Leading eigenpair of degenerate non-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Consider a non-symmetric matrix ${\bf A}_0$ with one eigenvalue $\lambda$ and all other eigenvalues are zero. The corresponding left $\bf u$ and right $\bf v$ eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ are normalised using the following relation: ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf v} = 1$.

Assume I perturb ${\bf A}_0$ with a small perturbation such that

$$ {\bf A} = {\bf A}_0 + \epsilon {\bf A}_1 $$

I know how to calculate the first order correction in the leading eigenvalue $\lambda$. However, what is the first order correction of the leading eigenvectors?

Comment: If ${\bf A}_0$ is rank-1 — is it? — why not replace it with something like $\bf a b^\top$?

Comment: It is rank 1 indeed, I can write $A_0$ as $\mathbf{ab}^\mathsf{T}$. Forgive my lack of understanding: how would this help me to find the first order perturbation in the eigenvectors?

Comment: Then you have a rank-1 update of $\epsilon {\bf A}_1$, right?  Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052997/339790)

Comment: Take a look at [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/904926)

Comment: Is ${\bf A}_0 = \lambda {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top$?

Comment: Yes it is, does this make the problem simple to solve?

Comment: Use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to compute the characteristic polynomial. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4535469/339790)

Comment: I had a look at the links. My current obstacles are that 1) I do not know the eigenvalues/vectors of $\mathbf{A}_1$; 2) Neither $\mathbf{A}_0$ nor $\mathbf{A}_1$ are symmetric, so I have difficulties applying a rank-1 update of $\varepsilon\mathbf{A}_1$. Finally, the matrix determinant lemma looks intersting, but I do not know how I can obtain an expression for the leading eigenvector from it?