# Calculating the diagonal entry of the adjugate of the Laplacian matrix of a complete graph.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, determinant, graph-laplacian

I am trying to directly calculate the adjugate of the Laplacian of the complete graph from which I know is given by $\tau(G) = n^{n-2}$ where $\tau(G)$ is the number of spanning trees of $K_n$.

I calculated it indirectly but my textbook (Norman Biggs, Algebraic Graph Theory chapter 6) says that it is a simple determinant manipulation on $nI-J$ where $J$ is the matrix of ones, but I cannot see this manipulation.
The Laplacian is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n-1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
-1 & n-1 & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-1 & -1 & \cdots & n-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The adjugate of the diagonal entry is the determinant of the Laplacian with the 1st row and column removed (w.o.l.o.g.).

The way I did it was by considering the eigenvalues of the $K_n$ with $0$ once and $n$, $n-1$ times and then used the formula which we derived in class from the Matrix Tree theorem giving $\tau(G) = \frac{1}{n}\prod$ non zero eigenvalues of Laplacian of $G$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790)

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this by considering the adjugate entry of the first row first column, $M= nI_{n-1} -J_{n-1} $.
Then, it is clear that $j = (1, \ldots, 1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n-1-(n-2) = 1$ and other $n-1$ eigenvectors are of the form $x_i = (1, 0, \ldots, 0, -1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ where $-1$ is in the $i$th row. There is $n-2$ of them and they all have an eigenvalue $n$.
So w.r.t. the eigenbasis of $M$,
$$
M=\operatorname{diag}(1,n,n, \ldots, n)
$$
which has a determinant $n^{n-2}$ as required.

Comment: Just a small criticism: here this is a very confusing idea to keep the same notation for a linear application and its representative matrix in a certain basis. Here what is $M$? if it is a matrix, what is written is not correct. If it is the linear application of the inner product space into itself, you should put an index on $M$ recalling in which basis you are representing a well defined endomorphism. Anyway, I have put a +1 to the answer because it is the proper way to consider the problem.