# Inverse and Projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, projection-matrices

Consider the following example first, we have matrix given as,($v\in\mathbb{R}^n$)
$$a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}v^4+2v^2v_iv_j$$
Now, define the following projection matrix,
$$I^{||}_{ij}=\frac{v_iv_j}{v\cdot v}$$
$$I^{\perp}_{ij}=\delta_{ij}-I^{||}_{ij}$$
Then we can rewrite the matrix as:
$$a_{ij}=v^4I^{\perp}_{ij}+3v^4I^{||}_{ij}$$
Thus the inverse can be written down as, (assuming the required conditions)
$$a^{-1}_{ij}=\frac{1}{v^4}I^{\perp}_{ij}+\frac{1}{3v^4}I^{||}_{ij}$$

My problem is the following: Suppose we now have matrix elements like this:
$$a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}(v^4+u^4)+2v^2v_iv_j+2u^2 u_iu_j+2u\cdot v(u_iv_j+v_iu_j)$$

Is there any way to find proper projection matrices?

Comment: If $v$ is a vector, what exactly do you mean by $v^2$ or $v^4$?

Comment: Also, it's not clear what exactly "proper projection matrices" is supposed to mean

Comment: $v^2=v\cdot v$, similarly it works for $v^4=(v^2)^2$. By proper projection matrix I meant writting the matrix elements in a way I explained in the example.

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation to the end of the second section of my answer in response to your (now deleted) comment

Comment: Also, see my latest edit: I've added explicit expressions for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Relating the answer to the simpler problem

Let $I$ denote the identity matrix. Taking $v$ to be a column-vector, your first matrix can be written in the form
$$
A = \|v\|^4 I + 2\|v\|^2vv^T.
$$
This is a [rank-1 perturbation of a scalar matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/81360), so its determinant, inverse, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors can all be easily found.  In particular, the eigenvalues of $A$ are given by $\|v\|^4$ and $3\|v\|^4$.

The projection matrices $I^{\perp}$ and $I^\|$ are the *spectral projections* of the symmetric matrix $A$, i.e. the orthogonal projections on to the eigenspaces of $A$ associated with the respective eigenvalues. Your expressions for $A$ and $A^{-1}$ arise as a consequence of this fact.

Note that $I^\perp$ and $I^\|$ are also the spectral projections associated with the rank-1 matrix $A - \|v\|^4 I = 2\|v\|^2 vv^T$.

---

### Justification of approach

The second matrix that you have written is
$$
B = (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4)I + 2 \|v\|^2 vv^T + 2\|u\|^2 uu^T + 2u^Tv(uv^T + v^Tu). \tag{1}
$$
To begin, we consider the matrix $M = B - (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4)I$,
$$
M =  2 \|v\|^2 vv^T + 2\|u\|^2 uu^T + 2u^Tv(uv^T + v^Tu).
$$
We can write $M$ in the form
$$
M = 2[vv^Tvv^T + vv^Tuu^T + uu^Tvv^T + uu^Tuu^T]\\
= 2(vv^T + uu^T)^2.
$$
Assuming that $u,v$ are linearly indepednent, both $(vv^T + uu^T)$ and hence $M$ will be rank-2 matrices, making $B$ a rank-2 perturbation of the identity matrix. The eigenvectors of $M$ will be the same as those of $B$.

For the remainder of this answer, I will assume that $u,v$ are linearly independent.

In order to find the eigenvectors of $M$, we begin by noting that for any vector $w \in \operatorname{span}(\{u,v\})^\perp$, we have $Mv = 0$. Because $M$ is symmetric, it follows that the remaining eigenvectors can be found within the invariant subspace $\operatorname{span}(\{u,v\})$. To that end, we set up the equation
$$
(M - \lambda I)(c_1 u + c_2 v) = 0 \iff\\
(M - \lambda I)\pmatrix{u & v}\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2} = 0 \iff\\
\pmatrix{u & v}^T(M - \lambda I)\pmatrix{u & v}\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2} = 0
$$
Let $Q$ denote the matrix $Q = [u \ \ v]$, and $c = (c_1,c_2)^T$. Because $u,v$ are linearly independent, $Q^TQ$ is invertible. We can write the above as
$$
Q^T(M - \lambda I)Q c = 0 \iff\\
(Q^TMQ - \lambda (Q^TQ)I)c = 0 \iff\\
(Q^TQ)^{-1}(Q^TMQ - \lambda (Q^TQ)I)c = 0 \iff\\
[(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^TMQ - \lambda I] c = 0.
$$
Thus, the vectors $c$ corresponding to eigenvectors of $M$ will themselves be the eigenvectors of the $2 \times 2$ matrix $(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^TMQ$. Once you have the two eigenvectors $y^{(1)},y^{(2)}$ of $M$ corresponding to the non-zero eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, if we take $I^{\|}_1,I^{\|}_2$ to be the spectral projections
$$
I^{\|}_1 = \frac{y^{(1)}{y^{(1)T}}}{\|y^{(1)}\|^2}, \quad I^{\|}_2 = \frac{y^{(2)}{y^{(2)T}}}{\|y^{(2)}\|^2}
$$
and $I^\perp = I - I^\|_1 - I^\|_2$, then it follows that
$$
M = 0 I^\perp + \lambda_1 I^\|_1 + \lambda_2 I^\|_2,
$$
so that $B = (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4)I + M$ is given by
$$
B = (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4) I^\perp + (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4 + \lambda_1) I^\|_1 + (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4 + \lambda_2)I^\|_2.
$$

---

### Step by step procedure

In light of the above, we can obtain a decomposition in terms of the "proper matrices" as follows: suppose that we are given vectors $u,v$ (associated with the matrix $B$ from Equation (1)). Denote $M = B - (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4)I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Denote $Q = [u\ \ v]$.

1. Compute the $2 \times 2$ matrix $P = (Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^TMQ$
2. Find eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs $\lambda_1, x^{(1)}$ and $\lambda_2, x^{(2)}$ of $P$
3. Obtain associated eigenvectors of $B$, $y^{(i)} = x^{(i)}_1 u + x^{(i)}_2v$ for $i = 1,2$.
4. Compute the spectral projection matrices,
   $$
   I^{\|}_1 = \frac{y^{(1)}{y^{(1)T}}}{\|y^{(1)}\|^2}, \quad I^{\|}_2 = \frac{y^{(2)}{y^{(2)T}}}{\|y^{(2)}\|^2}, \quad I^\perp = I - I^\|_1 - I^\|_2.
   $$
5. The matrix $B$ can be decomposed as follows:
   $$
   B = (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4) I^\perp + (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4 + \lambda_1) I^\|_1 + (\|u\|^4 + \|v\|^4 + \lambda_2)I^\|_2.
   $$

---

### Explicit expression for the eigenvalues

We find that $M = 2(QQ^T)^2$. It follows that
$$
(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^TMQ = \\
2(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T(QQ^TQQ^T)Q = \\
2(Q^TQ)^{-1}(Q^TQ)(Q^TQQ^TQ) = \\
2(Q^TQ)^2.
$$
It follows that the desired eigenvalues are the squares of the eigenvalues of $Q^TQ$ multiplied by $2$ and that the eigenvectors are equal to the eigenvectors of $Q^TQ$. We find that
$$
Q^TQ = 
\pmatrix{
u^Tu & u^Tv\\
v^Tu & v^Tv} = \pmatrix{\|u\|^2 & u^Tv\\
u^Tv & \|v\|^2}.
$$
With the quadratic formula, we find that the eigenvalues are given by
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac 12 \left(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 + \sqrt{(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2)^2 - 4[\|u\|^2\|v\|^2 - (u^Tv)^2]}\right)^2\\
\lambda_2 = \frac 12 \left(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - \sqrt{(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2)^2 - 4[\|u\|^2\|v\|^2 - (u^Tv)^2]}\right)^2,
$$
which simplifies further to
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac 12 \left(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 + \sqrt{(\|u\|^2 - \|v\|^2)^2 + 4(u^Tv)^2}\right)^2\\
\lambda_2 = \frac 12 \left(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - \sqrt{(\|u\|^2 - \|v\|^2)^2 + 4(u^Tv)^2}\right)^2.
$$
In the case where $u^Tv \neq 0$, the associated eigenvectors can be written as
$$
x^{(i)} = \pmatrix{u^Tv \\
\sqrt{\lambda_i/2} - \|u\|^2}, \qquad i =1,2.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.